# How to apply if else udf pandas to pyspark dataframe on a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to have a correct udf and apply on the dataframe

Create Spark df:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "v"))
```

pandas function:

```py
@udf("integer")
def add_con(x : pd.Series):
  if x>5:
    return x*x
  else:
    return x
df.printSchema()
df.withColumn('new', add_con(df.v)).show()
```

Output **(please correct the udf)**:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- v: double (nullable = true)

+---+----+----+
| id|   v| new|
+---+----+----+
|  1| 1.0|null|
|  1| 2.0|null|
|  2| 3.0|null|
|  2| 5.0|null|
|  2|10.0|null|
+---+----+----+
```

This worked:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.withColumn('new', f.when(df.v > 5, df.v * df.v).otherwise(df.v)).show()
# +---+----+-----+
# | id|   v|  new|
# +---+----+-----+
# |  1| 1.0|  1.0|
# |  1| 2.0|  2.0|
# |  2| 3.0|  3.0|
# |  2| 5.0|  5.0|
# |  2|10.0|100.0|
# +---+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing float field; but returning integer type. Also, argument type `pd.Series` is not required.

Here you go:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)]).toDF(*["id", "v"])

@udf("float")
def add_con(x):
  if x>5:
    return x*x
  else:
    return x
# 
df.withColumn('new', add_con(df.v)).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the working `pandas_udf`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.pandas_udf("integer")
def add_con(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  return pd.Series([e*e if e>5 else e for e in x])

df.withColumn('new', add_con(df.v)).show()
# +---+----+---+
# | id|   v|new|
# +---+----+---+
# |  1| 1.0|  1|
# |  1| 2.0|  2|
# |  2| 3.0|  3|
# |  2| 5.0|  5|
# |  2|10.0|100|
# +---+----+---+
```

For you it was not working, because you wanted to do operations with `pd.Series` object directly. It works if you work with elements of `pd.Series` and later convert the result back to `pd.Series`.